# I keep getting this error: "Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit"

Tags: swift

I keep getting this error:

```
Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
```

even though I put the self in the code. Please correct me.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let code = codeTextField.text
    if code == "TEST" || code == "Test" || code == "test" {
        var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message: "You are logging into The Test Zoo, right?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "welcomeButton", sender:self)
        }
```

There is more, but the yesAction needs correction.

Comment: *"even though I put the self in the code"* - where? Your code does not show the use of `self` being requested.

Comment: @rmaddy performSegue(withIdentifier: "welcomeButton", sender:self)

Comment: Call self.performSegue   You are calling performSegue on a viewcontroller, but in the closure it doesn't know in what context to call that method, so you need to tell it which instance of a viewcontroller to use, which is self.

Comment: @RPS1222 The message is not about the parameter you are passing to `sender`.

Comment: Read the error message carefully, which said use `'self.'`, notice the dot. The only place you can add `self.` with the dot at that line is right in front of the method call `performSegue`. Reading error message carefully does help to guess what's wrong even you don't know exactly.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 15):

`performSegue` is a method, which you're implicitly calling on `self`; the explicit version would be `self.performSegue(...)`.

Comment: @RPS1222, could you mark it as the correct answer for your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Simply change your line of code from `performSegue(withIdentifier: "welcomeButton", sender:self)` to `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "welcomeButton", sender:self)`