# How To run 'performSegue' in a function on Swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, func

I'm the first iPhone developer. My problem is that I want to run '`performSegue`' in the function. Works correctly within a typical button function. But I want to do it in a function. What should I do?

```swift
@IBAction func nextButtonFuc(_ sender: UIButton) {
       ...
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveScreen", sender: self) // it's worked
}
```

But it get Error

```swift
@IBAction func nextButtonFuc(_ sender: UIButton) {
       ...
       networkingCallback(objectvalue!,object,sender)
}
...
func networkingCallback( _ objectvalue: String,_ object: Any,_ send: UIButton) {
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveScreen", sender: send) //Error
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveScreen", sender: self) //Error
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveScreen", sender: send) //Error
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

**performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveScreen", sender: send)**

> Error is Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make
>   capture semantics explicit

**self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveScreen", sender: send) Error**

> Thread 18: signal SIGABRT

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of error you're getting while doing this can you post that.

Comment: @Abhishek Error posted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I keep getting this error: "Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53147808/i-keep-getting-this-error-implicit-use-of-self-in-closure-use-self-to-ma)

Comment: @Rengers  Did you see my question? I've already tried it.

Comment: @Rengers I already tried it at once,and I saw an error. Why is this question duplicated?

Comment: Try using @objc before your function might be SGABRT error is because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw a thread related error, I thought about how to it. And I thought it was an error caused by the asynchronous system. So I solved the problem through asynchronous execution.

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "makeNickname", sender: self) }
```